# how to have mutliple different instances of the same type in mock data

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

I have simple schema and server; Schema.js:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    people: [Person!]!
  }

  type Person {
    name: String!
    age: Int!
    job: String
  }
`;
```

And my server:

```
const mocks = {
  Person: () => ({
    name: () => "Henry Adams", 
    age: () => 21,
  })

};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, mocks: mocks });

server.listen().then(() => {
  console.log(`
     Listening on port 4000
     Query at http://localhost:4000
      `);
});
```

The above works as expected when I query for it on graphIQL, I know how to have multiple of the same exact instance if I change the server.js to the following:

```
const mocks = {
 Query: () => ({
    people: () => [...new Array(4)],
  }),
  Person: () => ({
    name: () => "Henry Adams", 
    age: () => 21,
  })

};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, mocks: mocks });

server.listen().then(() => {
  console.log(`
     Listening on port 4000
     Query at http://localhost:4000
      `);
});
```

This however is NOT what I am looking to do, instead I would like to do multiple different instances of the same type in my mock data, I have tried two different syntaxes and suprisingly cannot find this by googling:
Syntax one:

```
const mocks = {
  Person: () => ({
    name: () => "Henry Adams", 
    age: () => 21,
  }),

Person: () => ({
    name: () => "Berry, Lee", 
    age: () => 28,
  })

};
```

When I query with the above syntax only the second instance "Berry Lee" comes up.
The second syntax I assumed would work:

```
const mocks = {
  Person: () => ({
    name: () => "Henry Adams", 
    age: () => 21,
  }, 
   {
    name: () => "Berry, Lee", 
    age: () => 28,
  }),

};
```

I have the same problem with this second syntax, only the second type shows up when querying.

Comment: I think this will help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462944/is-it-possible-to-query-the-same-field-multiple-times-with-graphql, The reason is not works because Graphql return object, and Object have cannot be same keys that's why it replacing each other

Comment: This does help, however I still am unable to figure out how the code should look like in my `const mocks = {`, I am not sure where to put the alias with it still being a type of Person

Answer (score 0):

I got the original code from following the apollo odyssey tutorials 1 and 2 on the [apollo graphql site](https://www.apollographql.com/tutorials/) but doing some further digging I found [another post](https://upmostly.com/web-development/how-to-set-up-a-graphql-server-with-node-js) that brought my attention to `rootValue: root` and one work around I have found for the original code is the following (with the same schema as original post):

```
const mocks= [
  {
    name: "Henry Adams",
    age: 21,
  },
  {
    name: "Benny Lee",
    age: 29,
  },
];

const root = {
  people: () => mocks,
};

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, rootValue: root });
```

I am not sure if there is a way to do this using `mocks: true` or `mocks: mocks` yet so I will leave this question unanswered for some time for a possible more elaborate answer